# Why is the Youtube V3 Data API only returning 1 video result for this channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Question: Why am I receiving only 1 video from the below actions I take with the YouTube Data V3 API?  The example channel I am trying to pull videos from (https://www.youtube.com/user/JayLenosGarage/videos) has multiple videos.

I'm trying to fetch all the videos and their associated ids from the Youtube data api v3 for a specific channel.  Let's use the example channel JayLenosGarage.

So following this video on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdqsiFw74Jk&t=757s) which says to first get an "uploads" id by querying the channels#list api, then taking using the uploads id to run a query thru playlists#list api, I ran queries thru the API explorer (I also tried curl with an API_KEY) for JayLenosGarage channel on Youtube as follows and received the following output:

#### Channels#list api query:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg&key=<API_KEY>
# returns: 
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/z48ndyqvca6Iiuq8GhSM74uM6Ho\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/ZrtYB2hQFGE9E0BKmRhauZQb1kI\"",
   "id": "UCQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "likes": "LLQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
     "uploads": "UUQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
     "watchHistory": "HL",
     "watchLater": "WL"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

#### Playlist#list api query:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=UUQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg&key=<API_KEY>
# returns: 
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/DWOe-LD4_fSk0yC55HX_ZOrkuy4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 20
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/3CSCtGQNcyDVWQJAktkawoG7h7k\"",
   "id": "UUQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
    "title": "Uploads from Jay Leno's Garage",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hnjbaBzq7II/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hnjbaBzq7II/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hnjbaBzq7II/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hnjbaBzq7II/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hnjbaBzq7II/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Jay Leno's Garage",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Uploads from Jay Leno's Garage",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of all videos inside a channel, use the [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method. It will return a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

Here is the sample request that you need to do:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg&maxResults=50&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

> NOTE: You will only use the
>   [`channel.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
>   to get the information of that channel. It will not return the list of
>   videos inside it. Since you already know the channel ID of that
>   channel, then use the
>   [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)
>   to return all the videos inside of that channel.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: `Search` costs 100 quota, and is not the best choice to retrieve videos from a known channel. It is better to use `PlaylistItems` or `Activities`

Comment: The "user" question is all about **channel ID**, he/she said that he/she is trying to fetch all the videos and their associated ids from the YouTube data api v3 for a specific **channel**. So I give my answer in where you will use a channel ID instead of playlist id. But you are also correct if you want to use playlist id instead of channel id :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `PlaylistItems` instead of `Playlist`. I have limited the result to 1 result, but you can set maxResults to 50.

#### PlaylistItems#list api query:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg&key=<API_KEY>
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/cP-6KgbLq3nwDlAJIHbAFkoudaY\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 521,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/ATGgNMMgOoMbS2iqcgFL9h4B3yI\"",
   "id": "VVVRTUVMRmxYUUwzOEtQbThrTS00QWRnLkEwNmFrcGtuaF9J",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-11-07T07:09:25.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
    "title": "Restoration Blog: November 2016 - Jay Leno's Garage",
    "description": "Jay gives an update on some of the restorations going on in the garage.\n» Subscribe:  http://NBC.com/video/library/full-episodes/\nNBC YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/nbc\nFollow NBC: http://Twitter.com/NBC\nLike NBC: http://Facebook.com/NBC\nNBC Tumblr: http://NBCtv.tumblr.com/\nNBC Pinterest: http://Pinterest.com/NBCtv/\nNBC Google+: https://plus.google.com/+NBC\nNBC Instagram: http://instagram.com/nbctv\n\nRestoration Blog: November 2016 - Jay Leno's Garage\nhttps://youtu.be/A06akpknh_I\n\nJay Leno's Garage\nhttp://www.youtube.com/user/jaylenosgarage",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A06akpknh_I/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A06akpknh_I/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A06akpknh_I/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A06akpknh_I/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A06akpknh_I/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Jay Leno's Garage",
    "playlistId": "UUQMELFlXQL38KPm8kM-4Adg",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "A06akpknh_I"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Of course you can use `Search`,too, but you have to keep in mind that calling `Search` costs 100 Quota, and `PlaylistItems#list` costs only 1 quota.