# Is it possible to list all channels in an youtube api for an account?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I was able to use youtube's channel using new v3 API but it keeps returning only one channel even though I created 3 channels for testing on the same account. I referred various StackOverflow questions on the same but I have not got any solutions.
[Youtube start guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android) ,
 [Stackoverflow reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456080/why-is-the-youtube-v3-data-api-only-returning-1-video-result-for-this-channel),[Stackoverflow reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891136/youtube-channels-list-from-youtube-api-v3-returning-only-one-channel-in-android?rq=1)